# htaccess - the second url param is not visible

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`example.com/play/music` to `example.com/play.php?c=music`

here is my code which works:

```
RewriteRule ^play\/music$ play.php?c=music [L]
```

now I have an extra url param (`id` as `integer`) added:

`example.com/play/music/54`

need to be - `example.com/play.php?c=music&id=54`

here is my `beginning` try:

```
RewriteRule ^play\/music/\d+/?$ play.php?c=music&id=$1 [L]
```

the page is there but problem is with `id` param - php doesn't see it

could someone help and explain ?

also, maybe is possible to join both rules (with and without `id`) in one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs and make sure your .php files(eg: play.php etc) are residing along with .htaccess rules file.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?c=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]
```